# Maximum call stack size exceeded When trying to get an image by subscribing to it

Tags: angular

I'm trying to get an image through api subscription and I'm getting this error but the 
  image works completely fine.

```
    ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at SafeSubscriber._next (res-tabs.component.ts:20)
at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:185)
```

i Deleted this code and the error disappear but the image is gone:

```
       ngOnInit() {

        this.service.getImage(this.res.ID).subscribe((data: any) => {
        let base64String = btoa(String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(data)));
        if (base64String.length > 0) {
          this.Image = 'data:image/jpg;base64,' + base64String;
        }
        else {
          this.Image = null;
        }
      })
}
```

what should i do to delete this error ?

Comment: whats the size of the image you are trying to fetch? check if API request to the resource works or it waits long time retrying?

Comment: I suppose that you have an infinite loop somewhere and the snippet you've given here triggers it.